# cURL & Looping Through an Array

Tags: php, loops, curl, foreach, status

I'm attempting to create a script that would cycle through an array that would contain various file names with the use of cURL & '404' error detection. So in other words, if the initial defaulted file name comes up as '404', I would then create a loop function to cycle through the array while still running through the same cURL session. And when it detects status '200', it stops the loop & then proceeds to the next value sent by the client. I've tried using foreach(), but haven't had success. This is the code I'm using as a start.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['request'])) {
$req = $_POST['request'];
$url = $addr;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == '200') {
echo $url;
}
curl_close($ch);                                
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['request'])) {
    $req = $_POST['request'];
    $url = $addr;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

    for ($retry = 1; $retry <= $retry_max; $retry++) {
        $ret= curl_exec($ch);
        preg_match("/^HTTP\/[01\.]+ ([0-9]{3}[A-Za-z\(\)\- ]+)/",$ret,$getcode);
        if (strcmp($getcode[1], '200 OK') === 0) {
            break;
        } 
        else {
　　　       sleep(10);
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);                                
}
```